# upgraded to 22.04 from 20.0 startx fails

Tags: 22.04

https://pastebin.com/2wGZJvBT

Not able to get anything from the logs. Tried some debugging but didn't help. Any pointers plz

Sorry couldn't make much sense of the logs to debug further